# Does OLEDB 12.0 support FULL OUTER JOIN?

Tags: sql, oledb

ERROR:

```
Error: IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).
Syntax error in FROM clause.
```

QUERY:

```
Select * from [tbl Proctors$] p 
FULL OUTER JOIN [tbl Proctor History$] h 
ON p.Unique = h.Unique
```

The intriguing part is that the query works on `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN` but not with `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it without the `OUTER` keyword:

```
Select * from [tbl Proctors$] p 
FULL JOIN [tbl Proctor History$] h 
ON p.Unique = h.Unique
```

Just a guess.  If that doesn't help, please revise your question and identify the database you are connecting to with OLEDB.  This might be a setting on the data provider configuration.